# $\text{GL}_n:\mathbf{Alg}_k\rightarrow\mathbf{Set}:R\mapsto \text{GL}_n(R)$ is a representable functor

Tags: category-theory, functors, representable-functor

Following the definition of $\text{GL}_n:\mathbf{Alg}_k\rightarrow\mathbf{Set}:R\mapsto \text{GL}_n(R)$ found here: [functor from $\mathbf{Alg}$ to $\mathbf{Set}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2585279/functor-from-mathbfalg-to-mathbfset/2585300#2585300)

I would like to show that it is a representable functor.

**EDIT: wrong!**

For ease of notation, $F:=\text{GL}_n$ and $G:= \text{Hom}(k,-)$

Where $\text{Hom}(k,-):\mathbf{Alg}_k\rightarrow\mathbf{Set}:R\mapsto \text{Hom}(k,R):f\mapsto (\sigma\mapsto f\circ \sigma)$

I'll define the natural transformation as:

$$\alpha_R:\text{GL}_n(R)\rightarrow \text{Hom}(k,R):(a_{i,j})\mapsto (k\mapsto \sum a_{i,j}k)$$

this defines a natural transformation. But how natural is it? I.e. are there any more intuitive ways of doing this?

**EDIT: answer** (from answer below and adapted to my notations)

For ease of notation, $F:=\text{GL}_n$ and $G:= \text{Hom}(A_n,-)$

where
$$A_n=k[X_{11},\ldots,X_{nn},Y]/\left<1-Y\det(X_{ij})\right>.$$

Where $\text{Hom}(A_n,-):\mathbf{Alg}_k\rightarrow\mathbf{Set}:R\mapsto \text{Hom}(A_n,R):f\mapsto (\sigma\mapsto f\circ \sigma)$

I'll define the natural transformation as:

$$\alpha_R:\text{GL}_n(R)\rightarrow \text{Hom}(A_n,R)\\(a_{i,j})\mapsto (P(X_{11},\ldots,X_{nn},Y)+ (1-Y\det(X_{ij}))\mapsto P(a_{1,1},\ldots,a_{n,n},\text{det}(a_{i,j})))$$

Comment: It will certaibly not be represented by $k$. Do you think $GL_n(k) \simeq Hom(k,k)$ ?

Comment: Oups, I forgot to check that it is a bijection. What I gave is a natural transformation but not necessarily a natural isomorphism.

Comment: Only other idea is to represent it by $k^n$ but not sure that works

Comment: There's the same problem with $Hom(k^n, k) \simeq GL_n(k)$

Comment: In your natural transformation, you actually want $A \mapsto ([P] \mapsto P(a_{11}, \ldots, a_{nn}, \det A^{-1}))$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, $\text{GL}_n$ is an *affine group scheme*. It is represented by the $k$-algebra
$$A_n=k[X_{11},X_{12},\ldots,X_{21},\ldots,X_{nn},Y]/\left<1-Y\det(X_{ij})\right>.$$
An algebra homomorphism $\phi:A_n\to R$ is given by choosing the images
of $X_{ij}$ and $Y$, which must go to the inverse of $\det(\phi(X_{ij}))$
which ensures that $(\phi(X_{ij}))\in\text{GL}_n(R)$.

Waterhouse's book is a good introduction to affine group schemes.

Comment: I modified my answer. Can you check that it makes sense?